# Struggling to understand a given task

Tags: mysql, database, erd, rdbms

Need a little help with a task I was given for my assignment. I'm struggling with the wording and don't understand what needs to exactly be done. This question is linked to my previous 2 tasks which were to create an EERM based on my case study and then create a RDM based on the EERM. The next part says this but I don't understand what needs to be done.

3. **Consider and justify any decomposition or composition of your tables (Physical Design stage). Based on your final decisions produce a final Composite ERD Model uses QSEE. [10 Marks]**

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.
NOTE: QSEE is a program we use to create the diagrams.

Comment: Sounds like the task is to Normalize your table and then create ERD based on those tables.

Comment: The 3 tasks in your assignment correspond to conceptual (entity-relationship model), logical (relational model) and physical (tabular model) levels of data modeling. However, table diagrams are frequently (and incorrectly) called ERDs, Strictly mapping entity relations and relationship relations to tables can result in multiple tables with the same primary key, these are often denormalized in the physical model to reduce the final number of tables.